# A companion on the Journey Through Genius

Tags: textbooks, history-of-math

I find William Dunham's book [Journey Through Genius](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471500305.html) is a great text to use in a History of Mathematics course, but I wish it had more textbook-like content, e.g. reading comprehension questions, exercises, etc. for each chapter.

Does anyone know of a companion resource to this book and/or have one they'd be willing to share?

Comment: See also http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/has-anybody-used-mathematics-in-civilization-by-resnikoff-and-wells-or-journey-t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the information at the following link: https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/problems-for-journey-through-genius-the-great-theorems-of-mathematics

Description of link: On the 25th anniversary of the publication of Journey Through Genius, Convergence is pleased to make available to our readers William Dunham’s own problem sets to accompany the book. The 162 problems are divided into 12 problem sets, one for each chapter of the text.

Comment: Please add a summary of what can be found at the link (in case the link rots).

Answer (score 3):

John Stillwell's "Mathematics and its History" -- exercises and all.

I have used Stillwell's book to connect with the readings in Journey Through Genius, so it is worth looking at for more context and actual problems to work. 
I also have a friend who has used Dunham as a text and has created resources. I will obtain those for the OP, if Aeryk would like them.

Comment: This doesn't quite address OP's request. Could you expand your answer and explain why this book would be a reasonable substitute for Dunham's?

Comment: Ah! Yes. Sorry about that. I read companion as "extra resource." Edited.